# PHP - while loop change

Tags: php, while-loop

I have following while loop.

```
$readNews_SQLselect = "SELECT  ";
$readNews_SQLselect .= "id, content ";  // rows names
$readNews_SQLselect .= "FROM ";
$readNews_SQLselect .= "news ";         // table name


$readNews_SQLselect_Query = mysql_query($readNews_SQLselect);   

//$indx = 1;    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($readNews_SQLselect_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $ID = $row['id'];
    $CONTENT = $row['content'];

    echo '<li>' . $ID .' ' . $CONTENT . '</li>';

    //$indx++;

}

mysql_free_result($readNews_SQLselect_Query);
```

How would it look if I added `'$LIVE = $row['live'];'` with condition that **only rows with `live` value string of '0' should be displayed?** Live will be either 0 / 1 (VARCHART).

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: `if( $LIVE == 0 ) echo ... ` ?

Comment: If you ask a question on SO for every new line in your program it will take a looong time to develop it. get a book or tutorial

Comment: @yi_H - exercises only :) Is my third day using SQL / PHP.

Comment: @yi_H  - can you suggest any worth reading tutorials? I went through the whole safaribooks video library.

Comment: No idea.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772349/what-is-a-good-online-tutorial-for-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this to your query:

```
$readNews_SQLslect .= " WHERE live = '0'";
```

Comment: As last? Which one will be better, in the while loop or in SQL query?

Comment: The SQL Query of course : faster, less memory used to fetch data, less CPU used because of less whille loop iterations.

Comment: If you do it in your SQL query the database wont even have to look at those rows, if you do it in your loop your database would have to fetch the rows, and you have to have more logic skipping them.

Comment: Yes. It does make sense. Sorry for my silly questions - I'm new to the PHP / SQL stuff.

Comment: Silly questions dont exist ;) Just make sure you provide enough information, and show some effort, then people will answer you.

Answer (score 3):

Alter `$readNews_SQLselect`

```
$readNews_SQLselect = "SELECT  ";
$readNews_SQLselect .= "id, content ";   // rows names
$readNews_SQLselect .= "FROM ";
$readNews_SQLselect .= "news ";          // table name
$readNews_SQLselect .= "WHERE live='0'"; // condition
```

Answer (score 1):

1. alter your sql:

   ```
   $readNews_SQLselect = "SELECT  ";
   $readNews_SQLselect .= "id, content ";  // rows names
   $readNews_SQLselect .= "FROM ";
   $readNews_SQLselect .= "news ";         // table name
   $readNews_SQLselect .= "where live = '0' ";
   ```
2. if condition:

   `if ($row['live'] == '0') {
   echo '<li>' . $ID .' ' . $CONTENT . '</li>';
   }`

Comment: is there any other option as WHILE expr?

Comment: @RiaD, tahks! something went bad as i was typing an answer. @Pete, just add `... and ($row['live'] == '0')` to while... but it's not very good